# Reordering tables in Python is writing over the last two rows

Tags: python

I'm trying to rearrange the order of a CSV dataset in Python to allow me to append it to another file. I have headings `[a,b,c,d,e,f]` which needs to be changed to `[b,c,f,e,d,a]`. However, the `for` loop which I'm using is producing headings arranged in the order `[b,c,a,e,e,a]`. Presumably, it's because my index is updating mid-loop, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

See the code below:

```
def headings(file):
  correct_order = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f",]
  current_order = ["b", "c", "f", "e", "d", "a",]
  for i in range(0, len(current_order)):
    index = correct_order.index(current_order[i])
      for row in file:
        row.insert(index,row[i])
        row.pop(index+1)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: when `correct order list` is available with you, Why can't you use it instead of `current order list`?

Comment: Your `correct_order` has two occurrences of `b`

Comment: Sorry Ashwin, that was me mistyping this out here on stack exchange. The values are all distinct.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not exactly what you are looking for but have you considered using pandas?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(file)

correct_order = ["a", "b", "b", "d", "e", "f"]
df = df[correct_order]
df.to_csv(new_file)
```

Comment: Where did you notice `pandas` in OP?

Answer (score 0):

You're using two distinct indices, `i` which is a position in `current_order` and `index` which is where you mean to place it. You also put the loop for columns outside the loop for rows, which may cause some confusion.

The combination `row.insert(index,row[i])` inserts a copy of `row[i]` in a position `index` which may or may not be before `i`. The following `pop` assumes it was before. A cleaner way is to use the `pop` for the retrieval:

```
row.insert(index, row.pop(i))
```

This means the element that was removed is returned by `pop` then reinserted where it should be, never having a duplicate in `row`. However, this still doesn't get us the correct order because `i` is traversing by position, not caring if the value there was just inserted; this is a typical example of how mutating a list while iterating over it is troublesome.

Two other methods come to mind; forward or reverse permutation into a new list.

```
from_place = [current_order.index(k) for k in correct_order]
reordered_row = [row[k] for k in from_place]

to_place = [correct_order.index(k) for k in current_order]
reordered_row = [None] * len(correct_order)
for (i,v) in zip(to_place, row):
    reordered_row[i] = v
```

Frequently it is more robust to use names than indices. For instance, you can use [`csv.DictReader(f, current_order)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) and then read `[row[k] for k in correct_order]`, or perhaps better skip the reordering at all and use only keys.